# Spring boot - Autowired is null in authentication provider

Tags: spring-boot, autowired

I am trying to implement custom authentication as follows:

I have defined the filter as follows -

```
@Configuration
public class CamundaSecurityFilter {
   
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean processEngineAuthenticationFilter() {
SpringBeanAutowiringSupport. processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext ( this );
FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
registration.setName(“camunda-auth”);
registration.setFilter(getProcessEngineAuthenticationFilter());
registration.addInitParameter(“authentication-provider”,
“com.enterprise.servicing.framework.security.CamundaAuthenticationProvider”);
List urlList = new ArrayList<>();
urlList.add("/*");
registration.setUrlPatterns(urlList);
return registration;
}
```

I have defined the Authentication provider  as follows -

```
public class CamundaAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {
@Autowired
private TenantIdDao tenantIdDao;

}
```

I have created this tenantIdDao. If I Autowire this tenantIdDao in any @Service it works correctly. However this tenantIdDao CamundaAuthenticationProvider is always null.
Can you please help.

Answer (score 0):

The AuthenticationProvider is also declared as a Spring Bean?
Which package names are you using for the Spring Services where it works and where it does not? You may need to set @ComponentScan("org.example.xyz") correctly.

Also see e.g. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-autowire

(I guess you are aware of this example: https://github.com/camunda-consulting/code/tree/b1ce2e2f1e4e4215ba257e65cf37ad833ac0b8ba/snippets/springboot-security-sso )